# Interactive 3D visualization of word2vec model (gensim)

Tags: python, data-visualization, word2vec

i have created a word2vec model with gensim and am now looking for a way to visualize this.

I have already created a 2D plot, but it is very confusing. Assuming one performs a dimensionality reduction to 3 dimensions, is there a possibility to visualize these data points "interactively" within a jupyter notebook?
By interactive I mean that you might be able to navigate through the 3D plot and have a closer look at different points.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's possible, but might not be very satisfying. If your model is inherently of "high dimensionality" – dozens or hundreds of dimensions – then every such projection down to intuitively-understandable 2d or 3d will be throwing away most of what makes the high-dimension model valuable. Projections can sometimes preserve neighborhoods, and thus reveal some very-local structures in the data – at the expense of other patterns. But with many points, well-spread across the space, such visualizations often show less than some well-chosen tables-of-ranked-neighbors, or other bulk-calculated reports.

Answer (score 0):

[TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard) a visualization tool for Google's TensorFlow can visualize embeddings in [an interactive 3D plot](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_projector_plugin).

If you want to use, you first need to convert the embeddings into the TensorFlow format. Gensim has [a tool for that.](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/word2vec2tensor.html)

```py
python -m gensim.scripts.word2vec2tensor -i you_w2v.txt -o /tmp/my_model_prefix
```